# Why can't I programmatically add and delete topics using the Kafka Administration REST API for Bluemix's Message Hub?

Tags: apache-kafka, ibm-cloud, messaging, message-hub

I'm calling the IBM Bluemix Administration API for Message Hub (aka Kafka), as described [here](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/MessageHub/index.html#messagehub037).

Calling the endpoint `https://kafka-admin-prod02.messagehub.services.eu-gb.bluemix.net:443/topics` (using an appropriate `X-Auth-Token` value corresponding to our API key, and a GET verb) seems to work - it returns a list of the topics we've manually configured in the  Bluemix Message Hub admin screen.

However, calling the same URL with the verb POST and a body of `{name: 'mynewtopicname'}` and a `Content-Type` of `application/json` (this appears to be the correct syntax, according to the Swagger docs for the API) doesn't work - I get a result of "HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed". That seems to happen whether I use GET, PUT, POST or DELETE (which also means I cannot delete a topic).

Am I doing something wrong?

(I'm using Message Hub on the UK Bluemix instance, if it's relevant).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create topics you need to do a POST to the URL `/admin/topics`, not `/topics`. Give it a try and let me know if it works.

Comment: Luis, thank you! That works. Re-reading the swagger file, I can see that all the admin APIs start `/admin`. Seems like Postman may have autogenerate them wrong when it imported the Swagger file - or I just made a mistake! For the benefit of anyone else reading this, I also had to set the inbound "Content-Type" header to `application/json` - and it seems the JSON parser is *very* fussy, so the field name and value have to be in double-quotes; i.e. `{"name": "mynewtopicname"}`. Now it works! Thanks.

Comment: The JSON parser needs double quotes, otherwise is considered invalid. You can use any JSON linter or validator like this one http://jsonlint.com/ to know if your JSON is valid.

Comment: Luis, huh. I just double-checked that and you are right again ;) I've always found single quotes "just worked" in JSON, but I guess I've been using lax parsers. Seems they aren't valid, unlike in JS. You learn something every day :)